# HtmlUnit driver doesn't execute JavaScript

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit

I am new to HtmlUnit and am having some trouble with logging in.
Below code works perfectly fine for `FireFoxDriver` but fails for `HtmlUnitDriver`. The problem is it not executing `javascript` while clicking on "Login" link;

site url for html viewing: https://fleetworks.trimbletl.com/fleet/start.do

```java
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME_16);
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

driver.get(fleetWorkURL);

WebElement usernameElement = driver.findElement(By.name("j_username"));
usernameElement.sendKeys(username);

WebElement passwordElement = driver.findElement(By.name("j_password"));
passwordElement.sendKeys(password);

WebElement loginButtonElement = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log in"));
loginButtonElement.click();

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("headerFrame"));
```

StackTrace:

```
    13, 2013 2:47:54 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
    WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
    13, 2013 2:47:54 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
    WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
    13, 2013 2:47:55 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
    WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
   2013 2:47:56 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient loadDownloadedResponses
   INFO: No usage of download: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient$LoadJob@1b55ca5

   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10  seconds waiting for frame to be available: headerFrame
   Build info: version: '2.29.1', revision: 'dfb1306b85be4934d23c123122e06e602a15e446',  time: '2013-01-22 12:58:05'
   System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version:  '1.7.0_11'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:255)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:224)
at com.yukon.qasetup.xmlService.XMLService.main(XMLService.java:77)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Comment: this message in the log, can point to something ... WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'. not sure.

Comment: I think the warnings can be ignored; HtmlUnit seems to cope, even if it doesn't like the content type. The real issue is the exception where it can't find the frame _headerFrame_.

Comment: @user1991529: Is it a specific problem with the javascript which is supposed to be fired by the login button? Or does it fail for any javascript on the site?

Comment: Maybe you need to slow down HTMLUnit. Remember: HTMLUnit is way faster than firefox. That means maybe you click the login-button before the javascript is even loaded. (Selenium 2 doesn't wait for the page to load). Maybe you will need an while-constuct, that clicks the login-button as long as the headerFrame isn't visible.

Comment: I can only see "headerFrame" once I am logged in, if Yes? please share test username/password. May be I can help...

Comment: Can you add what version of Selenium you are using and what version of the browser you have on your local system?

Answer (score -1):

Your class HtmlUnitDriver is not part of the standard Selenium package, is it? As far as i know, for HtmlUnit you have to create a RemoteWebDriver instance with either DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnit() or DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnitWithJavaScript().

Can you loook inside your HtmlUnitDriver class? Maybe DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnit() instead of DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnitWithJavaScript() is used!?